# Javascript date input not displaying tomorrow properly

Tags: javascript

I have this to-do list code made in JS and whenever I set a date in the current day it works fine, but when I set it to tomorrow's date the code messes up and constantly sends a notification, any help?

here are the codes https://jsfiddle.net/hontsv8y/

index.html

```
<div id="questionBox">
    <span id="questionText">New Schedule</span>
    <span id="questionSubText">Please provide the title, date, and time of the reminder.</span>
    <input type="text" id="titleBox" placeholder="Title">
    <input type="date" id="dateInput" min="2019-01-01">
    <input type="time" id="timeInput" value="12:00">
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" onclick="saveSchedule()" value="Save">
    <a onclick="cancelSchedule()" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

script.js for the getting dates

```
const initialize = () => {
    if(Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
        document.getElementById('alertGrantBox').style.display = 'flex';
        alert("we have permission");
    }
    document.getElementById('title').textContent = `Hi, ${localStorage.name}!`;
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('topDisplayBox').style.height = '13vh';
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('topDisplayBox').style.transitionDelay = '0s';
        document.getElementById('topDisplayBox').style.transitionDuration = '0s';
    }, 100);
    const date = new Date();
    document.getElementById('dateInput').min = yyyymmdd(date);
    document.getElementById('dateInput').value = yyyymmdd(date);
};

const yyyymmdd = (date) => {
    let mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let dd = date.getDate();
    return [date.getFullYear(),
            (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
            (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
           ].join('-');
};

const tomorrow = (date) => {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    let mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let dd = date.getDate() + 1;
    return [date.getFullYear(),
            (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
            (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
           ].join('-');
};
```

and here is for displaying tomorrow on the web page

```
const update = () => {
    document.getElementById('notiElementsContainer').innerHTML = '';
    if(localStorage.reminders) {
        if(autoDelete()) {
            let funcReminders = JSON.parse(localStorage.reminders);
            reminders = JSON.parse(localStorage.reminders);
            document.getElementById('notiElementsContainer').innerHTML = '';
            for(let i = 0; i < funcReminders.length; i++) {
                let time = funcReminders[i].time.split(':');
                let ampm;
                if(time[0] - 12 < 0) {
                    ampm = 'am';
                    time = time[0] + ':' + time[1];
                } else {
                    ampm = 'pm';
                    if(time[0] == 12) {
                        time = time[0] + ':' + time[1];
                    } else {
                        time = time[0] - 12 + ':' + time[1];
                    }
                }
                let dateTime = new Date();
                dateTime = yyyymmdd(dateTime);
                let day;
                if(dateTime == funcReminders[i].date) {
                    day = 'today';
                } else if(tomorrow(new Date()) == funcReminders[i].date) {
                    day = 'tomorrow';
                } else {
                    day = funcReminders[i].date;
                }
                document.getElementById('notiElementsContainer').innerHTML = document.getElementById('notiElementsContainer').innerHTML + `<div class="notiElement" onclick="deleteRecord(event, ${i})"><span class="notiElementName">${funcReminders[i].title}</span><br><span class="notiElementTime">${time} ${ampm}, ${day}</span><div class="notiElementBottom"><span class="notification">Notification</span><input id="chkbox${i}" type="checkbox" class="chkbox" checked></div></div>`;
                if(notifications[i]) {
                    clearTimeout(notifications[i]);
                }
                notifications[i] = setTimeout(() => {
                    notiVisible();
                }, new Date(`${funcReminders[i].date} ${funcReminders[i].time}:00`).getTime() - new Date().getTime());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.

Comment: added a jsfiddle

Comment: And that fiddle is supposed to show what exactly now? Is this supposed to use desktop notifications? (I doubt those work from within a fiddle iframe to begin with.) Even with your fiddle, I have no idea what exactly the problem is supposed to be here now.

Comment: @CBroe, yes it's a desktop notification but when I set a reminder for tomorrows date the notification constantly sends a desktop notification and cant be deleted, but when I set a date for the current day or 2 days later it works fine